# caching twitter, facebook, gplus javascripts

Tags: facebook, caching, browser, twitter

I am trying to optimize my site due to the suggestions that google's pagespeed tool. it says me to make "Leverage browser caching" for these files;
`

```
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (3.6 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (3.6 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (5.2 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (13.2 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (14 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (14.5 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (14.9 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (15 minutes)
http://cdn.api.twitter.com/.../count.json?... (15 minutes)
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/css/share-button-css (16.8 minutes)
http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share (18.3 minutes)
http://connect.facebook.net/tr_TR/all.js (19 minutes)
http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js (30 minutes)
https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (60 minutes)
```

`
i know how to cache my own js,css files with mod_expires.c in .htaccess file but didnt understand how to cache those ?

and here is my .htaccess file
`

```
# BEGIN Compress text files
<ifModule mod_deflate.c>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml application/xml application/xhtml+xml text/css text/javascript application/javascript application/x-javascript
</ifModule>
# END Compress text files

# BEGIN Expire headers
<ifModule mod_expires.c>
  ExpiresActive On
  ExpiresDefault "access plus 5 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 2592000 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/x-javascript "access plus 604800 seconds"
  ExpiresByType text/html "access plus 600 seconds"
  ExpiresByType application/xhtml+xml "access plus 600 seconds"
</ifModule>
# END Expire headers

# BEGIN Cache-Control Headers
<ifModule mod_headers.c>
  <filesMatch "\.(ico|jpe?g|png|gif|swf)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(css)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "public"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(js)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private"
  </filesMatch>
  <filesMatch "\.(x?html?|php)$">
    Header set Cache-Control "private, must-revalidate"
  </filesMatch>
</ifModule>
# END Cache-Control Headers

# BEGIN Turn ETags Off
FileETag None
# END Turn ETags Off

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://domain.com$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com/.*$      [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cache those unless you make copies and host them on a domain you control.

Comment: so what do you suggest? store them on my own web server or leave them like that? thanks.

Comment: leave them like that. What rating is page speed and yslow giving you? Is your site loading quickly otherwise?

Comment: google page speed gives 88 (out of 100). i didnt test it with yslow yet.

Comment: I am also looking for a similar solution to reduce the number of requests to facebook and twitter servers. I guess we can use the FB API and write the PHP code ourselves, but I am not proficient in it.